Is assignment in Javascript template literals allowed?
Let's say I have a function that should return a HTML string with either <h1> or <h2> depending on whether a second argument is provided and true. Is it allowed to write it like this? (Notice that I'm assigning to level inside of the template string, then reusing the assigned value for the end tag.)
function heading(str, level) {
    return `<h${level = level ? '1' : '2'}>${str}</h${level}>`
}

I do realize that the sane way to write it would be to assign to level on a separate line, then use that inside the template literal.

Is assignment of this kind is allowed inside a template literal?

Is there some official documentation or standard that documents this?


I have not been able to find any kind of documentation (MDN or otherwise) that even mentions that assignment work inside of template literals. According to my own experiments it seems to work just fine though, as long as I don't initialize a variable (with let, const or similar) inside the template string. (Also, it seems to work regardless of whether 'use strict' is used or not.)

Yes, it's allowed. It's not necessary to list all allowed types of expressions. My only question would be, if the evaluation order is well-defined or if it's allowed that ${level} is evaluated before ${level = level ? '1' : '2'}

Does this link answer your question https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#string_interpolation The usage is ${expression} and "expression" is not limited. "as long as I don't initialize a variable (with let, const or similar)" That's a statement. Statements are not allowed, only expressions.

Personally I would not write code like that as a general practice. If it's mysterious enough that you have to ask about it here, then maybe breaking the code up into more than one statement would make it clearer.

@jabaa That seems to answer the question, yes. :) (Thank you!) Is there any particular reason why you didn't want to write your answer as an answer?

Because I don't know if the evaluation order is well-defined and IMO it's an important part of the answer. This is a necessary detail in order to say if your code will always work.

@jabaa Evaluation order of expressions is well-defined in javascript and is always left-to-right, bottom-up
